# Help finding replacement for diode (F4)

Tags: diodes, identification

i do need to replace a diode that fell off / got lost on a circuit board. I do have an identical element that i used to take pictures.

The diode in question is the one on the right, marked "F4":

[image]

The size is about 1mm from left to right.
I measure a voltage drop of 0.26v from right to left, so i figure it's a Schottky Diode. However as the diode is soldered onto the board, i know the measurements need to be taken with a grain of salt.

Looking for identification of the "F4" i find mostly Zener diodes though.

If anyone could point me in the direction, this would be much appreciated. Ideally in a way that helps me a place where i can order replacement.

To summarize my question: I need to understand what diode the "f4" one is, so i can buy a replacement for it.

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Hi, could you please reorganize your question to a better format? The way it is right now it is not clear what your question is.

Comment: When I google "F4 diode" I find a ton of Schottky diodes, Here is a link to one of them check the dimensions, if they match you can probably replace it with one of them. "https://www.mouser.de/Semiconductors/Discrete-Semiconductors/Diodes-Rectifiers/Schottky-Diodes-Rectifiers/Datasheets/_/N-ax1mj?keyword=F4"

Comment: Sorry if i was being unclear.
My question: I need to understand what diode the "f4" one is, so i can buy a replacement for it.

Comment: What is this diode's function? Depending on what it's doing there, it might be very particular that it needs to be this one exact diode, or it might be that you can use any old diode.